# JavaScript Events (onclick and onLoad)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

1. The Password field should be displayed with some asterisk's by default
2. When I click on password textbox that asterisk should be blank (`onClick`) and the newly entered should data be in text form
3. When I click on reset button again that data should be converted to asterisk
   i.e `onload`

The code is currently like this; I need to change this code:

```
<td><fmt:message key="selfcare.reset.password"/></td>
<td><form:input path="credentialVO.password" maxlength="16"/>
    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_resetSelfcarePassword" value="Reset" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input type needs to be "password"

```
<input type="password"  .....>
```

Also, from what I understand from your question, you can do one of the following:

1. for newer browsers use the HTML5 placeholder attribute.
   http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder
2. for supporting most of the browsers use the jquery watermark plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/